# JavaScript with Angular nested object model generating from response (infinite deep)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I've got an angular application which is getting a response from the server about particular object. This should generate the UI for user which can be filled and sent back to server.

Response is an JSON object which contain "nodes" of data. Which inside can have another nodes. Like a tree view.

The problem is with such response I was able to generate the first layer using ng-template.

Here is a working codepen example which i'm trying to get work.
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NNMepw

The structure of response is:

```
{   
    "name": "MainNameOfOption",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "propertyOne": {
        "name": "Option1",
        "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "ID": {
              "name": "ID",
              "type": "text",
              "properties": {},
              "enum": []
            }
          },
          "enum": null
        },
        "propertyTwo": {
          "name": "Option2",
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "enabled": {
              "name": "Field",
              "type": "boolean",
              "properties": {},
              "enum": []
            },
            "Option": {
              "name": "Option",
              "type": "list",
              "properties": {},
              "enum": ["Option1", "Option2", "Option3", "Option4"]
            },
            "Objective": {
              "name": "Objective",
              "type": "object",
              "properties": {
                "GoNext": {
                  "name": "GoNext",
                  "type": "text",
                  "properties": {},
                  "enum": []
                },
                "GoBack": {
                  "name": "GoBack",
                  "type": "text",
                  "properties": {},
                  "enum": []
                }
              },
              "enum": null
            },
            "Holder": {
              "name": "Holder",
              "type": "object",
              "properties": {
                "Type": {
                  "name": "Type",
                  "type": "list",
                  "properties": { },
                  "enum": ["Option1", "Option2", "Option3", "Option4"]
                }
              },
              "enum": null
            },
          },
          "enum": null
        }
      },
      "enum": null
    };
  }
]);
```

So this should create a UI.
The UI needs to be generated dynamically depending on which type of option is it.
The HTML which is generating the View is:

```
<body>
  <div ng-controller="basicDemoCtrl">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="col-sm-12">
          </div>
          <script type="text/ng-template" id="nodes_renderer.html">

            <div>
              <label > {{ node.name }}: </label>
              <input type="checkbox" ng-if="node.type == 'boolean'"
              ng-model="result[parent.name][node.name]" ng-init="result[parent.name][node.name] = result[parent.name][node.name] || 

false"></input>
              <input type="text" ng-if="node.type == 'text' || node.type == 'int'" ng-model="result[parent.name][node.name]" ng-

init="result[parent.name][node.name] = result[parent.name][node.name] || ''" />
              <select ng-if="node.type == 'list'" ng-options="enum as enum for enum in node.enum" ng-model="result[parent.name]

[node.name]" ng-init="result[parent.name][node.name] = result[parent.name][node.name] || ''" > <option value=""> </option> 

</select>
            </div>
            <ol>
              <li ng-repeat="node in node.properties" ng-include="'nodes_renderer.html'">
              </li>
            </ol>
          </script>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
              <div id="tree-root">
                <ol ng-model="Object.properties">
                  <li ng-repeat="node in Object.properties" ng-init="parent = node" ng-include="'nodes_renderer.html'"></li>
                </ol>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-6">
              <pre class="code">{{ result | json }}</pre>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

So for now I'm able to create the JSON object from that which is

The Model which i'm expecting to be created is:

```
{
"Option1": {
    "ID": ""
    },
"Option2": {
    "Option": "",
    "Field": false,
    "Holder" : { 
         "Type": "Option1", 
     }
    "Objective" : {  
         "GoBack": "",
         "GoNext": ""
     }
  }
}
```

But sadly i'm stuck with object created like that:

```
{
  "Option1": {
    "ID": ""
  },
  "Option2": {
    "Option": "",
    "Field": false,
    "Type": "",
    "GoBack": "",
    "GoNext": ""
  }
}
```

As you can see i was able to make the first layer of the the generated object so it's splitted properly into PropertyOne and PropertyTwo but I can not force somehow to generate the objects inside the PropertyTwo.

I'm stuck at this point.
Does anyone had the same issue ? Succeed with generating dynamically object inside the nested object ?

I've attached the "almost" working codepen link above.

Comment: I think you'd be better off parsing out your object in a service and then feeding that into your view instead of trying to create it in your view.

Answer (score 0):

As I saw your clarification - why not just create a dedicated server that will parse the JSON and create the tree model directly and  not as a side effect of angular template rendering.